# Integer data compression for transfer in C without external libraries

Tags: c, encoding, compression

I googled ans searched here a bunch without a fitting solution. The title is maybe a bit weird or not fully accurate, but let me explain:
My IoT device collects a bunch of data every second that I can represent as a list of integer. Here is an example of one row of sensor reads (the zeros are not always 0 btw):

```
230982 0 4294753011 -9 4294198951 -1 4294225518 0 0 0 524789 0 934585 0 4 0 0 0 0
```

On trigger I want to send the whole table (all rows until then) to my computer. I could just stringify it and concatenate everything, but wonder if there is a more efficient encoding/compression to reduce the byte count, both when storing in RAM/flash and for reduced transfer volume. Ideally this could be achieved with integrated functions, ie no external compression libraries. I am not that strong with encoding/compression, hope you can give me a hint.

Comment: You know the data, so you must know how to compress it (e.g. you know the limits). Maybe just sending them as binaries number would be enough (and you should know the size in bytes)

Comment: The best strategy depends on the type of data. Difficult to determine it with only a short amount of data. One simple possibility: for each integer, use 1 or 2 bits to specify the number of bits/bytes that are used to encode the integer, e.g. 1 byte/4 bytes/8 bytes ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo Generally in IoT devices, the computing capacity is very limited, and the power consumption must remain very low. But the post is not clear about such constraints effectively.

Comment: @Damien Yeah, I read it more carefully and removed my comment.

Comment: A simple compression algorithm is [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) that you could apply to your binary or stringified data.

Comment: It looks like the posted data items fit in 32 bits if you consider some of them as unsigned and some as signed values. Are those large values such as 4294225518 truely unsigned? They look suspiciously like 32-bit signed values in disguise (e.g. 4294225518 looks like it should be -741778). If so, you may be able to squeeze the values into 24 bits or 3 bytes.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, everything is 32bit, even though some numbers are quite small. You have a good eye for values, these numbers are indeed unsigned negatives (I tried to play around with signed and unsigned since people said the sign adds extra, but forgot to remove it here). How would I get an int32 into 24bits? Can I get integers of value 0-100 somehow into less bytes? Some are already even binary, so that's easy to fix converting to binary form as suggested in the answer by user694733

Comment: @André Well it depends on the range. If the large unsigned values in your example were converted to signed values, all the numbers shown would fit in 21 bits including the sign bit, but it is more convenient to store them as 24 bits. Of course, if you need to store numbers outside the range -8388608 to 8388607 then 24 bits will not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zlib/Zstd libraries are better suited for doing general purpose compression. If I may assume that you don't want to use any third party libraries, here is a hand coded version of some naive compression method, which saves half of the bytes of the input string.

The basic idea is very simple. Your strings will at most have 16 different characters which can be mapped to 4-bits rather than typical 8-bits. SEE THE ASSUMPTIONS BELOW. You can try `base16`, `base64`, `base128` encodings too, but this is the simplest.
Assumptions:

1. First you'll convert all your numbers into a string in decimal format.
2. The string won't contain any other characters than `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,.`,`space`, and a `comma`.

============================================================================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline char map(char c)
{
        switch(c) {
        case ' ' : return ('/' - '*');
        case '\0': return 0;
        default  : return c - '*';
        }
        return 0;
}

static inline char revmap(char c)
{
        switch(c) {
        case '\0'     : return 0;
        case '/' - '*': return ' ';
        default       : return c + '*';
        }
        return 0;
}

char *compress(const char *s, int len)
{
        int i, j;
        char *compr = malloc((len+1)/2 + 1);

        j = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < len; i += 2)
                compr[j++] = map(s[i-1]) << 4 | map(s[i]);

        if (i-1 < len)
                compr[j++] = map(s[i-1]) << 4;

        compr[j] = '\0';
        return compr;
}

char *decompress(const char *s, int len)
{
        int i, j;
        char *decompr = malloc(2*len + 1);

        for (i = j = 0; i < len; i++) {
                decompr[j++] = revmap((s[i] & 0xf0) >> 4);
                decompr[j++] = revmap(s[i] & 0xf);
        }
        decompr[j] = '\0';
        return decompr;
}

int main()
{
        const char *input = "230982 0 4294753011 -9 4294198951 -1 4294225518 0 0 0 524789 0 934585 0 4 0 0 0 0 ";
        int plen = strlen(input);
        printf("plain(len=%d): %s\n", plen, input);

        char *compr = compress(input, plen);
        int clen = strlen(compr);

        char *decompr = decompress(compr, clen);
        int dlen = strlen(decompr);
        printf("decompressed(len=%d): %s\n", dlen, decompr);

        free(compr);
        free(decompr);
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! Really good answer. I don't understand fully what happens, but I will check the code slowly to learn. Just ran it and despite two errors (compr and decompr assign a void* from malloc, so it has to be " = (char*)malloc") it worked perfectly.

Comment: @André Not casting a `void *` is perfectly valid in C but not in C++. Maybe you enabled some flags that results in errors. Anyhow, thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Possibly, I used the C Playground and it threw the error, even though normally it resembles C well, but maybe it's a weird C/C++ hybrid.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to simply dump data out in binary form. It may be smaller or bigger than string form depending on your data, but you don't have to do any data processing on device.

If most of your data is small, you can use variable length data encoding for serialization. There are several, but CBOR is fairly simple.

If your data changes only very little, you could send only first row as absolute values, and remaining rows as delta of previous row. This would result in many small numbers, which typically are more efficient in previously mentioned encoding systems.

I wouldn't try to implement any general purpose compression algorithms without any experience and external libraries, unless you absolutely need it. Finding suitable algorithm that compresses your data well enough and with reasonable resource usage can be time consuming.

Comment: That's pretty much what I just thought based on the comments on my original question. I will treat each sensor as a column. The values sometimes change little or random, but I could use differential storage to reduce byte count and maybe RLE as suggested by @the busybee to reduce it even more if nothing changes. In binary form it would make it most compact with little onboard computation.